# Specifying ViewPager tabs through XML

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

According to the [TabLayout docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html):

> If you're using a ViewPager together with this layout, you can call
>   setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) to link the two together. This layout
>   will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles.
>
> This view also supports being used as part of a ViewPager's decor, and
>   can be added directly to the ViewPager in a layout resource file like
>   so:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Is it also possible to set the tab names through XML, rather than programmatically? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="top" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Tab" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: you can use DataBinding library, create a BindingAdapter and set those tabs in the way you want.

Comment: No, that won't work. `TabLayout` will remove any tabs set with `TabItem`s before populating itself with tabs created from the `ViewPager`'s `Adapter`.

Comment: This might be a typo, but I just noticed that you have the `TabItem` in the wrong spot, anyway. `TabItem`s only work inside the `TabLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. good catch - it was a typo when copy and pasting the code :)